# Qualitative explanation for equal heat capacities in ideal gases

Tags: physical-chemistry

Hello I was wondering the following thing. As you all know from statistical thermodynamics, if only translational states are available for a given ideal gas (such as He, Ne, Ar, Xe), the isochoric heat capacity sums up to 1.5 R.

The derivation of this value is clear for me, however, I have a little bit of a doubt why all ideal monoatomic gases should have the same isochoric heat capacity, that is, the amount of energy to heat up a sample by one kelvin. Wouldn't it take a bit more energy to heat up heavier elements, or is this compensated by the fact that temperature is proportional to kinetic energy, so the heavier elements have the same temperature even though they have lesser velocity according to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: So your picture would be the following. Imagine we throw $\pu{100 kJ}$ of heat to "$N_\mathrm{A}$" atoms of $\ce{He}$, and separately to $\ce{Xe}$, both at the same initial temperature. Their final temperature will be the same. But it is not intuitive how this can be true, becuase $\ce{Xe}$ is much bigger, so you'd think that it needs more energy to get to a higher temperature. Right?

Comment: Indeed, it would seem that way

Comment: Isn't that because we need mass and velocity for kinetic energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heavier particles do move slower than lighter particles at the same temperature.

[image: kinetic model of ideal gases]

However, this does not affect the net kinetic energy because of **equipartition of energy**, which states that (translational) kinetic energy of ideal gases is fixed at a given temperature.

#### Thermodynamics

$$
\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V = C_V
$$

According to **equipartition of energy**, $\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{R}T$ is the average molar energy available to each degree of freedom. Since monoatomic ideal gases have only three (translational) degrees of freedom, the energy is given by $\dfrac{3}{2}n\mathrm{R}T$. Substituting in Eq. (1):

$$
\begin{align}
C_V &= \left(\dfrac{\partial \dfrac{3}{2}n\mathrm{R}T}{\partial T}\right)_V
&= \dfrac{3}{2}n\mathrm{R} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

**Note:** The mass of the gas plays no role in the heat capacity of a monoatomic ideal gas.

#### Kinetic Theory

According to the kinetic theory, the kinetic energy of (independent and identical) particles is given by:

$$
\mathrm{KE} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2}mv_{i}^2 \tag{2}
$$

Equating Eqs. (1) and (2):

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{3}{2}n\mathrm{R}T &= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2}mv_{i}^2\\
\implies \dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{m}{M}\mathrm{R}T &= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2}mv_{i}^2\\
\implies \dfrac{3}{2}\mathrm{R}T &= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{2}Mv_{i}^2\\
\implies \sum_{i=1}^{N}v_{i}^2 &= \dfrac{3\mathrm{R}T}{M} 
\end{align}
$$

**Note:** The velocities are weighted with molecular masses, meaning that heavier particles do move slower on average.

This is a graph of the type $y = \dfrac{c}{x}$, as visualized earlier.

Comment: Yeah the derivation is clear for me, however I was asking how one can explain this qualitatively

Comment: @Mäßige i hope the latest edit addresses your comment.